# Dropdown Menu To Call jQuery based on Selection

Tags: php, jquery, html-select

I'm attempting to create a dropdown menu that calls some jQuery based on the selection in the dropdown, this changes the data that appears within a table.

My Code:

Select Menu

```
<select style="margin-bottom: 8px; width: 14%; float: left;" onChange="eventtime('day');">
<option onSelect="eventtime('1');" value="1">Monday</option>
<option onSelect="eventtime('2');" value="2">Tuesday</option>
<option onSelect="eventtime('3');" value="3">Wednesday</option>
<option onSelect="eventtime('4');" value="4">Thursday</option>
<option onSelect="eventtime('5');" value="5">Friday</option>
<option onSelect="eventtime('6');" value="6">Saturday</option>
<option onSelect="eventtime('7');" value="7">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
function eventtime(day){
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assets/pages/habshine/events.php",
    data: "day=" +day,
     success: function(msg){
          $("#main").html(msg);
     }
});
}
```

This isn't working.
Does anybody have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what's actually happening?

Comment: @BrandonGano I expect it to call the jQuery which then changes data within a table on the page, which uses the Day. Nothing actually happens at all

Comment: It could be that a typo is preventing the function from being called at all. I'd set a breakpoint or add a `console.log` at the beginning of `eventtime` to see if it's being called. It could be that `events.php` is returning an error code, so the `success` callback is never fired. I'd also put a breakpoint/log in there to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Events are not supported on `<option>` cross browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function eventtime(){
    var day=$('#select_box').children(":selected").val();
    console.log("Day= "+day)
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assets/pages/habshine/events.php",
    data: "day=" +day,
     success: function(msg){
          $("#main").html(msg);
     }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="margin-bottom: 8px; width: 14%; float: left;" onChange="eventtime();" id="select_box">
<option value="1">Monday</option>
<option value="2">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4">Thursday</option>
<option value="5">Friday</option>
<option value="6">Saturday</option>
<option value="7">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

If the Select box value will change then,Go to **eventtime()** function. This function first,filter the selected day corresponding value and Post to below url.

Comment: Explanation will be added.please ask if any doubt in this code.